# How do I programmatically activate the screen recorder on a Lenovo Mirage Solo Daydream?

Tags: android, daydream

Currently, can press volume button and menu to activate screen recording on Lenovo Mirage Solo daydream device.  Is there a way to trigger this same function programmatically?

I've looked through the documentation and cannot find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
KeyEvent volDown = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN);
Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(volDown);
KeyEvent menuDown = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent. KEYCODE_MENU);
Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(menuDown);

KeyEvent volUp = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN);
Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(volUp);
KeyEvent menuUp = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent. KEYCODE_MENU);
Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(menuUp);
```

I haven't tested this because I don't have this phone, but here is my best guess. The first four lines press the volume and menu keys down (`ACTION_DOWN`), and the second four lines release them (`ACTION_UP`). Hopefully it works for you :)
I'm assuming this works with menu and volume-down, but if it's volume-up then just swap `KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN` for `KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP`